# Python socket: server 'receiving' more than buffsize even after client terminates

Tags: python, sockets, networking

This is my first Stack Overflow question, I hope I got it right.

I'm trying to work with Python sockets and have a basic echo client and server. 
Client sends some data to server, server prints it and sends it back, client prints it and closes, server should close.

In an attempt to try sending different data types (another story) I've run into this problem that I can't explain. 
On the client I'm generating a string larger than 1024 and sending it to the server which only recv(1024), the server should print the data, print the length of it, and send it back. 
Instead the server prints data and length, sends it back, at which point the client terminates as expected but the server continues to print the data and length two more times. 
Why does this loop continue? If there is more than 1024 bytes in the buffer, shouldn't they be discarded? Or will the 'next' 1024 bytes be in 'data' and the loop continues until all the data is processed and printed?

I'm at a loss to explain why this happens, shouldn't the while loop on the server stop when the connection to the client is broken? 
It seems the server is receiving multiple times, but the client only sends once, hence why I'm thinking this might be something to do with the buffer size? 
Any help appreciated. Code below.

Client

```
  1  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  2
  3 import socket
  4 import random
  5
  6
  7 HOST = '127.0.0.1'
  8 PORT = 5099
  9
 10 def create_string(s):
 11     for x in range(1, 10):
 12         s = s + s
 13     return s
 14
 15 msg = create_string("Example ")
 16 print(len(msg))
 17
 18 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
 19     s.connect((HOST, PORT))
 20
 21     s.send(msg.encode())
 22     data = s.recv(1024)
 23
 24     print('Received ', repr(data))
```

Server:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env python3
  2
  3 import socket
  4 import time
  5
  6 HOST = '127.0.0.1' # Localhost address
  7 PORT = 5099
  8
  9 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
 10     s.bind((HOST, PORT))
 11     s.listen()
 12     conn, addr = s.accept()
 13     with conn:
 14
 15
 16         print('Connected by', addr)
 17         while True:
 18
 19             data = conn.recv(1024)
 20             print(data.decode())
 21             print(len(data))
 22             time.sleep(2)
 23             if not data:
 24                 break
 25             conn.send(data) # send and sendall() give same result.
 26             time.sleep(1)
```

I've added some sleep functions to see what is happening and also tried stepping through with pdb.

Here's a screenshot of how it ends up. The client terminates after the first printing function on the server.

[screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XXrw.png)

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Answer (score 0):

A TCP socket is a byte stream.  You will receive the same number of bytes in the same order as sent.  The size of `recv(n)` doesn't matter.  You will receive 0 (if the socket closes) or 1 to n bytes.  You are not guaranteed to receive the number of bytes requested, and they are not guaranteed to be broken up in the same way they were sent.

You are responsible for making sense of the byte stream.  Buffer the data received until you have a complete message.  You define when a complete message means.

Also, `send()` isn't guaranteed to send all the bytes you requested either.  Check the return value and re-send the portion of the buffer that didn't send or use `sendall()`.